# How can I added the instance Id to google LogginAppender

Tags: java, google-cloud-logging

I'm using the logger appender below for a google cloud run revision instance and want to add the instance id to it. A basic print statement has the instance ID and it would be helpful if an actual log message could have it as well. I am dumping the logs with org.slf4j.

```
<appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
    <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel>
</appender>

<root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how java handle the logs in GCP but I found some resources that may help you.

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#run-gce

I hope these documentations will help you to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a simple logger enhancer which added the instance Id as a label.

```
package util;

import com.google.cloud.MetadataConfig;
import com.google.cloud.logging.LogEntry;
import com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingEnhancer;

public class InstanceIdEnhancer implements LoggingEnhancer {
    @Override
    public void enhanceLogEntry(LogEntry.Builder logEntry) {
        logEntry.addLabel("instanceId", MetadataConfig.getInstanceId());
    }
}
```

And then modifying my logback file to

```
<appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
    <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel>
    <enhancer>util.InstanceIdEnhancer</enhancer>util
</appender>

<root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
</root>
```